# run ffmpeg on a folder and all if it's subfolders, converting only certain video types

Tags: ffmpeg, video, batch

How to use ffmpeg to convert the entire content of a folder with all of it's subfolders, but only targeting videos with the formats `.mpg`, `.avi` and `.vob`.

Moreover, I want the output folders to be the same as the input folders and the output name to be the same as the input name, but the output file extension of course to be `.mp4`.

I tried writing a batch script to do so, but to no avail.

```
@echo off
    
set "source_folder=C:\path\to\source\folder"

for /r "%source_folder%" %%F in (*.avi *.mpg *.vob) do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%F" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k "%%~dpnF.mp4"
   )
```

Comment: What error / result are you getting?

Comment: no such file or directory

Comment: Why batch and not e.g. PowerShell?

Comment: there are some parentesis missing....

Answer (score 1):

```batch-file
@echo off 

cd /d "D:\The\Full\Path\To\Folder\"

set "_FFbin=C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
set "_FFswt=-hide_banner -v error -stats -c:v libx264"
set "_FFswt=%_FFswt% -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k"

for /f ^delims^= %%i in =;(' 2^>nul %__AppDir__%where.exe /r . *.avi *.vob *.mpg
    ');= do echo/ & echo\ Input: "%%~dpnxi" && echo\Output: "%%~dpni.mp4" && =;(
         "%_FFbin%" -y -i "%%~dpnxi" %_FFswt% "%%~dpni.mp4" && echo========= );=
```

---

---

- Some further reading:

  - **[set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**
  - **[Where](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)**
  - **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
  - **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
  - **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**
  - **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**
  - **[Use parentheses/brackets to group expressions in a Windows batch file](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html)**